# Simple Slopes: significance testing

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction

Can somebody explain me how to test whether simple slopes are significant?
...and is it necessary to test the significance of the simple slopes or would it be sufficient to plot the slopes and describe the effects?

I performed a moderation analysis with a regression, i.e. a regression with an interaction. The interaction is significant. I calculated the simple slopes for different Levels of the moderator, mean + / - 1 SD. But I do not know how I can test whether These slopes are significant.

Comment: Does "simple slope" mean something different than "slope"?

Comment: I do not think so. In the context of Moderation Analysis this term is used when you calculate slopes for different levels of the moderator.

Answer (score 2):

You said that *the interaction is significant*. In a model with different slopes in different groups the meaning of interaction is that the slopes are different! So I think you have already answered your own question, unless you mean something different with *significance of slopes*.